# Is there a specific poetry technique to refer to font types?

Tags: terminology, poetry

[**Source**](http://www.nebo-lit.com/poetry/dawe/enter-without-so-much-as-knocking.html)

What I mean is a part of the poetry that is in block letters or in italics or in bold to emphasise something. Is there a particular terminology that I can refer this as? An example:

```
                  When Mom won the 
Luck's-A-Fortch Tricky-Tune Quiz she took him shopping 
in the good-as-new station-wagon (£ 495 dep. at Reno's). 
Beep, beep. WALK. DON'T WALK. TURN 
LEFT. NO PARKING. WAIT HERE. NO 
SMOKING. KEEP CLEAR/OUT/OFF GRASS. NO 
BREATHING EXCEPT BY ORDER. BEWARE OF 
THIS. WATCH OUT FOR THAT. My god (beep) 
the congestion here just gets (beep) 
worse every day, now what the (beep beep) does 
that idiot think he's doing (beep beep and BEEP).
```

Stanza 3 of enter without so much as knocking by Bruce Dawe.

Comment: The title of the poetry is "enter without so much as knocking" there's no caps in the title. Just have to clarify this.

Comment: Always include a link to the source if available. Clarifications are better made using the [edit] link under your question, not in comments. There are no universally agreed-upon conventions regarding poetry and fonts. (There are no italic or bold fonts in your text, in any case.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant My text is merely an example of block letters being used. There could be other poems out there that uses bold or italics.

Comment: A poet may choose italic, bold, and lower or upper case (or "block letters" if you prefer) as he or she wishes. There is no convention governing such usages. Typography is a vast, unfettered domain, as cummings, Whitman, Levertov, Padgett, Rexroth, Ackerman, Jay-Z and countless others have made clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of font is an aspect of *typography*, and so one may discuss the typographic techniques that the poet has used. Beyond that you can discuss the purposes and the effects of the choice of lettering.

When this is taken to the extreme, it is sometimes called [concrete, pattern or shape poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_poetry). In concrete poetry the form on the page is more important than its reading. There is a blurred line between "typographic poetry" and "poetic typography".